# SIGSEGV when trying to install Java EE SDK 7 on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, java

I tried to fresh install Java EE SDK 7 Update 45 on OS X 10.9.1

I did

`export DISPLAY=:0`

then

`sudo ln -sf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin/java`

and

`export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"`

followed by

`sh Downloads/java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64.sh`

This results in

```
Extracting the installer archive...
Extracting the installer runtime...
Extracting the installer resources...
Extracting the installer metadata...

Welcome to GlassFish installer

Using the user defined JAVA_HOME : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
Entering setup...
SwixML 1.5 (#144)
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000011eb05ab9, pid=844, tid=50439
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode bsd-    amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x000000011eb05ab9
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core     dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /var/folders/yj/fk34rncs79vcfyq_853334qr0000gn/T//hs_err_pid844.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
/tmp/install.123113224830/install/bin/engine-wrapper: line 139:   844     Abort trap: 6           ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_OPTIONS} -    Dinstall.engine=${theInstallEngine} -Dinstaller.resources.url=${MEDIALOC}/ -Ddefault.resources.url=file:${INSTALL_HOME}/lib/resources/ -classpath ${theCP} -Dsims.native-file-dir=${INSTALL_HOME}/lib     org.openinstaller.core.EngineBootstrap ${INSTALLPROPS}
```

What could cause this problem?

Comment: The DISPLAY line should be unnecessary. OS X Java does not use X11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://www.ozkanserin.com/2013/12/05/java-ee-7-installer-crashes-on-mac-osx-mavericks/).

`$ sudo ./java_ee_sdk-7-unix.sh -a silent_install_answer_file -l /Users/username/temp -s`

silent_install_answer_file:

```
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.CLUSTER_NAME=c1
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.CREATE_CLUSTER=false
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.DOMAIN_NAME=domain1
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.INSTANCE_NAME=instance1
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.SERVER_ADMIN_PORT=4848
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.SERVER_HOST_NAME=localhost
ConfigType.Option.CREATE_CLUSTEREDINSTANCE=CREATE_CLUSTEREDINSTANCE
ConfigType.Option.CREATE_DOMAIN=CREATE_DOMAIN
ConfigType.Option.CREATE_STANDALONEINSTANCE=CREATE_STANDALONEINSTANCE
ConfigType.Option.NO_CONFIGURATION=NO_CONFIGURATION
Domain.Configuration.ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
Domain.Configuration.ADMIN_PASSWORD_REENTER=password
Domain.Configuration.ADMIN_PORT=4848
Domain.Configuration.ADMIN_USER=admin
Domain.Configuration.CREATE_SERVICE=false
Domain.Configuration.DOMAIN_NAME=domain1
Domain.Configuration.HTTP_PORT=8080
Domain.Configuration.SERVICE_NAME=domain1Service
Domain.Configuration.START_SERVER=false
InstallHome.directory.INSTALL_HOME=/usr/local/glassfish4
InstallType.Option.CONFIG_ONLY=CONFIG_ONLY
InstallType.Option.INSTALL_AND_CONFIG=INSTALL_AND_CONFIG
InstallType.Option.INSTALL_ONLY=INSTALL_ONLY
InstallUserType.Option.ADVANCED_USER=ADVANCED_USER
InstallUserType.Option.BASIC_USER=BASIC_USER
JDKSelection.directory.HIDDEN_JDK=
JDKSelection.directory.JDK_FROM_LIST_CHOICE=false
JDKSelection.directory.JDK_LIST=
JDKSelection.directory.JDK_TYPE_IN=
JDKSelection.directory.JDK_TYPED_IN_CHOICE=false
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.CREATE_NEWACCT=CREATE_NEWACCT
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.DUMMY_PROP=
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.SKIP_REGISTRATION=SKIP_REGISTRATION
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.USE_EXISTINGACCT=USE_EXISTINGACCT
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.USERNAME=
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.USERPASSWORD=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.COMPANYNAME=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.COUNTRY_DROP_DOWN=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.COUNTRY=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.EMAIL=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.FIRSTNAME=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.LASTNAME=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.PASSWORD=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.REENTERPASSWORD=
StandaloneInstance.Configuration.INSTANCE_NAME=instance1
StandaloneInstance.Configuration.SERVER_ADMIN_PORT=4848
StandaloneInstance.Configuration.SERVER_HOST_NAME=localhost
UpdateTool.Configuration.ALLOW_UPDATE_CHECK=true
UpdateTool.Configuration.BOOTSTRAP_UPDATETOOL=true
UpdateTool.Configuration.PROXY_HOST=
UpdateTool.Configuration.PROXY_PORT=
```

Be patient as it may take a while without any visual feedback.